# How to Convert an Object received from an SQL Lookup into a string in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm new to Stack and ADF, so please excuse me if my question is lacking some information. I am looking up a datetime value in our database using an Lookup Activity in ADF. This the result of the lookup:

```
 "value": [
        {
            "": "2023-01-19T10:16:34Z"
        }
    ],
```

I want to put 2023-01-19T10:16:34Z into a variable as a string. What is the best practise for this? The type of the value is Object.

Thanks in advance.

I was able to convert the value into an array. (see below) But that is not what I need.

```
@array(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0])
```

Comment: Try using `string`  function instead of array

Comment: Hey @Aswin, 

Thanks for your answer.

I tried that earlier, but the result of that script is: {\"\":\"2023-01-19T10:16:34\"}

I need the value 2023-01-19T10:16:34Z. Is there a way to model the string? Can I use substring for example?

Thanks!

Comment: Check below answer. If your key doesn't have name, use replace function to replace `"":` with `''` (empty string).  `@replace(string(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0]),'"":','')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **string()** instead of array function.
I tried to repro this with sample input.

**Sample input (Lookup table):**

```json
"value":
 [
     { "col1": "2023-01-19T10:16:34Z" }
 ]
```

- Set variable activity is taken and variable s1 of string type is set using this activity. `@string(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].col1)` is given as an expression to convert the lookup activity output to string.

**Result**
[image]